# How can I reset a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form in C# that has items such as buttons, a background, and text. When a button is clicked, I want the form to go to a blank state (nothing on the form) so I can add other things. I don't want to have to have Form1 and Form2 that switch between each other. Simply, I just don't want to switch between two different forms.

Comment: do you want the form to hide ? Do you want the form to display at all?

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to know what you're actually trying to accomplish. It's _possible_ you just need two different `UserControls`. Or maybe you want a `TabControl`, and the user can just switch between tabs instead of clicking a button. Or maybe you just want to remove all the items from the `Form`'s `Controls` collection. Please consider providing [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is to design two separate [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)s and just swap them out at runtime.  That's cleaner than trying to delete and add individual controls.

Comment: Or two panels, one hidden.  Hide one, show the other and visa-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear the controls on the form - simply call:

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```

A better way would be to dispose of all the controls like so.  You must iterate the controls backwards when dispose as on each dispose the indexing of the controls is altered:

```
foreach (int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    this.Controls[i].Dispose();
}
```